# win32 parts are being blacked out when taking screenshots of vmware

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, win32gui, win32con

When trying to take a screenshot of vmware machine the inside of it is being blacked out for some reason.

[blank screen proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5oNN.png)

Where as I expect to see the following:

[visible screen proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvUma.png)

The code seems to work fine when testing on calculator and few other applications, what could be causing this issue?

```py
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con

def backgroundScreenshot(hwnd, width, height):
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj=win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0,0),(width, height) , dcObj, (0,0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'test.bmp')
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

title="Win10_64 - VMware Workstation 16 Player (Non-commercial use only)"
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
print(hwnd)
backgroundScreenshot(hwnd, 900, 780)
```

Comment: [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity), for example. In this case, though, it's probably due to non-GDI rendering of the client area.

Comment: I get black image for calculator on Windows 10 2004 but it works on Windows 8.1. What's your Windows version?

Comment: You can check [New Ways to do Screen Capture](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/) to see if it helps.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT the window cannot be minimized, windows 10 64bit 10.0

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import numpy as np

def screenshot(window_title=None):
    if window_title:
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
        if hwnd:
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            x, y, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
            x, y = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x, y))
            x1, y1 = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x1 - x, y1 - y))
            im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, x1, y1))
            
            img = np.array(im)
            return img
        else:
            print('Error: Virtual Machine is not running!')
    else:
        im = pyautogui.screenshot()
        return im


im = screenshot('Win10_64 - VMware Workstation 16 Player (Non-commercial use only)')
if im:
    im.save('test.png')
```

This is alternative way of taking screenshots, it does work however it doesn't achieve the desired functionality of being able to take a screenshot of the window while it's in the background since other tabs are being also screenshoteted.

Problem solved, cause: unknown (if anyone has some suggestions for the cause, I would appreciate it)

[Virtual Machine Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkC0M.png)

[Master screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLsGD.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYjDE.png)